# FileSystemWatcher, why wont it catch a create event copied by Canon EOS

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

I am using a FileSystemWatcher object to catch the creation of *.jpg´s in a folder.
So far it worked as a charm, i tested it by dragging jpg´s into the folder, but then i started taking pictures on a Canon EOS 600D. The cameras software copies the picture from its flashcard to a the targeted folder but no event gets fired.
If i drag the file out of and then into the targeted folder the create event fires just fine.

Does anyone know if a program can deposit a file in a way that the SystemFileWatcher doesnt notice it?

theres no reaction at all, no event, no exception, not even an error on the error event.

Comment: Please show you watcher code. There is a good chance that you are filtering out interesting events (i.e. checking only for create).

Comment: The O/S and version of .NET may influence the answer.